# Django tutorial: 'polls.Choice' has no ForeignKey to 'polls.Choice'.

Tags: python, django

I got this error when im coding in the second part of the django tutorial, i don't know why, i have the same code that the website.

Django 1.8.3

```
ERRORS:
<class 'polls.admin.ChoiceInline'>: (admin.E202) 'polls.Choice' has no ForeignKey to 'polls.Choice'.

System check identified 1 issue (0 silenced).
```

My models.py

```
    import datetime

from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone

class Question(models.Model):
    question_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField('date published')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.question_text

    def was_published_recently(self):
        return self.pub_date >= timezone.now() - datetime.timedelta(days=1)

class Choice(models.Model):
    question = models.ForeignKey(Question)
    choice_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    votes = models.IntegerField(default=0)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.choice_text
```

My admin.py

```
from django.contrib import admin

from .models import Choice, Question

class ChoiceInline(admin.StackedInline):
    model = Choice
    extra = 3

class QuestionAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    fieldsets = [
        (None,{'fields': ['question_text']}),
        ('Date information', {'fields': ['pub_date'], 'classes': ['collapse']}),
    ]
    inlines = [ChoiceInline]

admin.site.register(Choice, ChoiceInline)
admin.site.register(Question, QuestionAdmin)
```

I really will preciate the help, I really have no idea what is the problem , and want to finish this tutorial

Comment: You shouldn't register Choice at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `ChoiceInline` has already been included in your `QuestionAdmin` by setting

`inlines = [ChoiceInline]`.

This means that when you edit a question, you will be able to add, edit and delete that question's choices at the same time.

You are getting the error because of this line:

```
admin.site.register(Choice, ChoiceInline)
```

This is invalud, becayse you can't register a model with an `Inline`. You can only register a model with a `ModelAdmin` class. To stop the error, simply remove this line from your code.

If you want to edit choices by themselves, you need to define a `ChoiceAdmin` class and register that.

```
admin.site.register(Choice, ChoiceAdmin)
```

Or, if you don't need any customisation, you don't actually need a model admin.

```
admin.site.register(Choice)
```

Comment: I remove the ChoiceInline, and stay `admin.site.register(Choice)` but when i got to Add Choice in admin, does not appear extra 3, just 1

Comment: Registering the choice model with `admin.site.register(Choice)` lets you add and edit **choices** by themselves. To see your choice inline with 3 extra choices, add or edit a **question**.

Comment: Oh, i see... Thanks very much, Alasdair :P